# Wordpress how to replace the Strings/URLs in "wp_nav_menu" output or %3$s thing?

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm currently using something like:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
               'theme_location' => 'primary', 
               'container' => false, 
               'items_wrap' => '<ul id="primary-main-menu" class="primary-main-menu-en">%3$s</ul>',
               'fallback_cb' => false
));
```

Then i got a pretty decorated menu with my own class, etc.
But now another more tricky step is:

- How can i **replace** the url links inside that menu object output? (To replace, for example: `www.domain1.com` to `www.domain2.com`)
- In other words, actually i want to replace the strings inside `%3$s` thing. How to?

Note:
I used `walker` but i could not use walker altogether with `items_wrap` option and/or the output is something distorted. So i gave up `walker`. Any sharp idea please?

Comment: You should ask questions about wordpress in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ and you can make your own menus in wordpress admin dashboard and call them with "'menu' => 'menu-name'"

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. I'm not asking to make my own menu.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of defining your own Walker class you can simply hook into the default Walker using the filter `walker_nav_menu_start_el`. Here you can modify the link HTML before it's outputted.

Below is a working example of your use-case:

```
function mytheme_walk_nav_menu_items($output, $item, $depth, $args) {

    if ( $args['theme_location'] === 'primary' ) {
        $output = str_replace( 'www.domain1.com', 'www.domain2.com', $output );
    }

    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'mytheme_walk_nav_menu_items', 10, 4 );
```